non-parametric methods to generate high-probability sample sequences from an existing univariate continuous time series
If I have an existing time series (of univariate continuous values), how can I generate a "realistic" sequence of future samples? Assume the samples of the existing time series are fairly dependent on each other over time (for example, a daily stock price may exhibit protracted bull or bear market trends over a period of many consecutive days, or a sensor data stream that may have different regimes or slow oscillation over time). So "realistic" here means that the future samples sequence would look entirely natural based on the existing time series. But I can't assume the existing time series has any simple formal probability distribution (normal, lognormal, etc.) Surely there must be a way to generate new samples based solely on the existing empirical time series data in a non-parametric fashion?
One technique I have read about that may be applicable is a higher order Markov chain, but I am confused how I would sample from the empirical distribution (the existing time series of continuous values)? Would I have to use bins? Is there anyway to do this without discretizing the continuous values? Any ideas or feedback would be welcome.

Not sure as well, but I think if you could model positive autocorrelations into your stochastic process, it would help alot.
